# Reading software-specific text file data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text, txt

A software I use outputs the results as text txt files in the following way [Output Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n8d5.png).

or like here for example:

```
------------------------------------
Joint 1
------------------------------------
Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2
16.000  1174    7.45
17.000  1174    7.87
18.000  1174    7.64
------------------------------------
Joint 2
------------------------------------
Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2
16.000  1174    7.45
17.000  1154    7.87
18.000  1124    7.64
------------------------------------
Joint 3
------------------------------------
Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2
16.000  1174    7.55
17.000  1174    7.67
18.000  1174    7.84
```

Now I want to analyse the results for each joint and dont know how to import the text file into pandas in a feasible way. Optimally I want something like this [Wanted Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peqha.png) or a separate pandas dataframe or numpy array / list for each joint.
Like here for example:

```
Joint 1                 Joint 2                 Joint 3
Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2 Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2 Time    Parameter1  Parameter 2
16.000  1174    7.45            16.000  1174    7.45            16.000  1174    7.55
17.000  1174    7.87            17.000  1154    7.87            17.000  1174    7.67
18.000  1174    7.64            18.000  1124    7.64            18.000  1174    7.84
```

Would be great if someone can help with how to deal with the hyphen line breaks of the output text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide an MRE that makes creating an answer much more efficient ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Timus: thanks for your hint. I already added an example of the output and an example of the desired outcome :)

Comment: But only as images -- that's not the way it's supposed to be. The users should be able to cut and paste. That shouldn't be a problem for your "Output Text File"?

Comment: @Timus: Thank you again for your suggestion. I have edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slightly modified *Output Text File*

```
------------------------------------
Joint 1
------------------------------------
Time    Parameter1  Parameter2
16.000  1174    7.45
17.000  1174    7.87
18.000  1174    7.64
...
```

pasted into a file named `output.txt` this

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dfs = []
with open('ouput.txt', 'r') as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        joint = line.strip()
        next(file)
        df_str = ''
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith('--'):
                break
            df_str += line
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)
        df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[joint], df.columns])
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

produces the following output (`print(df)`)

```
  Joint 1                        ... Joint 3                      
     Time Parameter1 Parameter2  ...    Time Parameter1 Parameter2
0    16.0       1174       7.45  ...    16.0       1174       7.55
1    17.0       1174       7.87  ...    17.0       1174       7.67
2    18.0       1174       7.64  ...    18.0       1174       7.84

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

at least for me. (This stuff is a bit fickle, the exact formatting of the file is rather important.) The list `dfs` contains one DataFrames for each "joint", if you rather want to deal with them individually.

If you are more interested in a vertical arrangement with `Time` as part of the index then the replacement

```
...
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
        df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[joint], df.index])
...
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

produces

```
              Parameter1  Parameter2
        Time                        
Joint 1 16.0        1174        7.45
        17.0        1174        7.87
        18.0        1174        7.64
Joint 2 16.0        1174        7.45
        17.0        1154        7.87
        18.0        1124        7.64
Joint 3 16.0        1174        7.55
        17.0        1174        7.67
        18.0        1174        7.84
```

The difference in the file is that `Parameter 2` is replaced with `Parameter2`. So the question is: Is whitespace in the header names possible? If so, things get more complicated.

Taking up your idea in the comment this should also work:

```
# Extracting the column names (could also be done manually)
with open('ouput.txt') as fin:
    for _ in range(3):
        next(fin)
    columns = ['Joint'] + next(fin).split()

# Transforming file into a csv-file (ignoring the header lines)
with open('ouput.txt', 'r') as fin, open('ouput-tidy.csv', 'w') as fout:
    next(fin)
    for line in fin:
        joint = line.strip()
        next(fin)
        next(fin)
        for line in fin:
            if line.startswith('--'):
                break
            fout.write(','.join([joint] + line.split()) + '\n')

# Reading csv-file in DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('ouput-tidy.csv', header=None)
df.columns = columns
df.set_index(['Joint', 'Time'], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: A third and big thank you. Everything worked indeed, but yes I have some trouble with the parameter names. Not a big issue though. But it seems to take ages when I run this on 4000 row text file. Do you think it is better to first change the format of the text file --> save it in the updated data format as another text file and then import the "tidied" text file directly into pandas ?

Comment: @OmarShehataUBW Yes, this might be a good idea! I have added a suggestion how this could be done (it does here, for the sample frame).